# While making app for release in flutter, does it includes test folder?

Tags: flutter

I am currently doing some test & that includes file upload. So for that testing I am adding some files in under 
`test/assets/some_1MB_image.jpeg` 
`test/assets/some_5MB_video.mp4`
`test/assets/some_3MB_song.mp3`
Does it means while releasing my app it will increase the size?

Let's say previously if it's **15MB**, after this changes, will it increase to **15.9MB** (or roughly **16MB**)?